Factor Scores explain less Variance than Item means in a multilevel cfa
I conducted a multilevel confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) in lavaan on repeated measures questionnaire data (satisfaction with travel scale). 42 participants had about 9 measurements on average (unbalanced) after naturalistic multimodal travels.
The questionnaire wants to measure satisfaction with travel as a hierarchical model with three sub-factors: Positive Deactivation (high valence low arousal), positive activation (high valence, high arousal and cognitive evaluation. Each measured with 3 items on a 1 to 7 Likert scale.
Overall model fit is not bad and all local fit statistics are significant and satisfactory
For the within model, the hierarchical structure for the latent variables offered the least bad fit
and for the between model a 1 factor structure offered the least bad fit compared to 2 or 3 factors, but the hierarchical structure did not converge properly.
I interpret the within latent variable as satisfaction with a specific travel (as intended, as the factor structure offers a proper fit).
But since the between model is a 1 factor structure and the pooled within and between covariance matrices are kind of built independently, I would interpret the between latent variable rather as an overall rating-propensity instead of a mean/stable satisfaction with travel.
I computed the within and between factor scores with lavpredict()
Supporting my interpretation, Neuroticism (measured with 2 items, bfi10) explains 20% of the variance of the between latent variable factor scores.
Over all travels, there is no significant relation between the duration of travel and the satisfaction with travel. Neither with our within latent variable scores nor with the averaged item scores (n=400)
The relationship becomes significant (but very small) when we only take trips with about the same route into account(n=132).
But interestingly, the Trip-duration explains more variance of the averaged item scores ($R^2$=.076) than of the within latent variable scores ($R^2$=.028).
I thought that the relationship would become stronger with the latent variable scores of the within satisfaction variable. If I create a new variable where I add the within an between scores, $R^2$ becomes .076, as the averages item scores.
How would you interpret what is happening here? I know that the relationships are pretty small, but does it make sense that a general rating propensity would increase this relationship? Is it a bad sign that the trip duration doesn’t explain more variance of the within factor scores than of the item score averages? This topic is pretty abstract so I would love to know different opinions on this.
Thanks in advance!
